# Фоновые задачи в Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, мобильная-разработка

Попытался реализовать работу фоновой задачи в Android и iOS как это описано в [статье](https://robgibbens.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/).

Для этого в `MainPage` я создал `Label` с именем `ticker` и в код формы добавил следующий код:

В конструкторе вызываю метод `HandleReceivedMessages();`, который выглядит следующим образом:

```
void HandleReceivedMessages()
{
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<TickedMessage>(this, "TickedMessage", message =>
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                ticker.Text = message.Message;
            }
            catch { }
        });
    });

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CancelledMessage>(this, "CancelledMessage", message =>
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                ticker.Text = "Cancelled";
            }
            catch { }
        });
    });
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку запуска задачи выполняется следующий код:

```
var message = new StartLongRunningTaskMessage();
MessagingCenter.Send(message, "StartLongRunningTaskMessage");
```

А при нажатие на кнопки остановки следующий:

```
var message = new StopLongRunningTaskMessage();
MessagingCenter.Send(message, "StopLongRunningTaskMessage");
```

Также я определил несколько вспомогательных классов:

```
public class StartLongRunningTaskMessage { }

public class StopLongRunningTaskMessage { }

public class TickedMessage
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class CancelledMessage { }
```

И класс с логикой фоновой задачи:

```
public class TaskCounter
{
    public async Task RunCounter(CancellationToken token)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            for (long i = 0; i < long.MaxValue; i++)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                await Task.Delay(250);

                TickedMessage message = new TickedMessage {Message = i.ToString()};

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { MessagingCenter.Send(message, "TickedMessage"); });
            }
        }, token);
    }
}
```

В Android-проекте в MainActivity.cs в метод OnCreate я добавил следующий код:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<StartLongRunningTaskMessage> (this, "StartLongRunningTaskMessage", message => {
    var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(LongRunningTaskService));
    StartService (intent);
});

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<StopLongRunningTaskMessage> (this, "StopLongRunningTaskMessage", message => {
    var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(LongRunningTaskService));
    StopService (intent);
});
```

А также определил сервис с несколькими методами:

```
[Service]
public class LongRunningTaskService : Service
{
    CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                //INVOKE THE SHARED CODE
                TaskCounter counter = new TaskCounter();
                counter.RunCounter(_cts.Token).Wait();
            }
            catch (System.OperationCanceledException) { }
            finally
            {
                if (_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    var message = new CancelledMessage();
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => MessagingCenter.Send(message, "CancelledMessage"));
                }
            }
        }, _cts.Token);

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (_cts != null)
        {
            _cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            _cts.Cancel();
        }

        base.OnDestroy();
    }
}
```

В iOS-проекте в AppDelegate.cs в метод FinishedLaunching добавил следующий код:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<StartLongRunningTaskMessage>(this, "StartLongRunningTaskMessage", async message =>
{
    _longRunningTaskExample = new iOSLongRunningTaskExample();
    await _longRunningTaskExample.Start();
});

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<StopLongRunningTaskMessage>(this, "StopLongRunningTaskMessage",
    message => { _longRunningTaskExample.Stop(); });
```

И также определил класс:

```
public class iOSLongRunningTaskExample
{
    nint _taskId;
    CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public async Task Start()
    {
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        _taskId = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask("LongRunningTask", OnExpiration);

        try
        {
            //INVOKE THE SHARED CODE
            TaskCounter counter = new TaskCounter();
            await counter.RunCounter(_cts.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
        finally
        {
            if (_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var message = new CancelledMessage();
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => MessagingCenter.Send(message, "CancelledMessage"));
            }
        }

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(_taskId);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
    }

    void OnExpiration()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

В результате запущенная в "активном" режиме работы приложения задача останавливается, когда я закрываю приложение. В чем может быть дело? На видео у автора статьи все работает, а у меня почему-то нет. Может ли быть причина в том, что данный метод уже устарел и для реализации фоновой задачи требуются дополнительные действия?

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию служба запускается в том же процессе, что и приложение Android. Можно запустить службу в собственном процессе, задав для свойства ServiceAttribute.IsolatedProcess значение true

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/

Answer (score 0):

Какая модель телефона? Некоторые модели телефонов, хуавей, самсунг и xiaomi, убивают все фоновые процессы при выходе из приложения или спустя некоторое время. При этом пользователю не дают возможность изменять настройки. Проблема эта длится уже с 2018 года Google не может решить эту проблему до сих пор.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122098785

Даже сайт создали по этой проблеме: https://dontkillmyapp.com/